# Consistently getting error "Emulator: ANSICON: cmd.exe: unsupported process." in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Any project I test in Android Studio fails and gives the error "Emulator: ANSICON: could not obtain the parent process." I have tried several different emulators and completely reinstalling but have had no success. Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the architecture (x86 vs x64) of the emulator and os match?

Comment: @Swordfish Yes, they are both x64.